# What cd/dvd burning software should I use?

Tags: software-recommendation, dvd, cd, burning

I have tried countless cd/dvd burning software on ubuntu 12.04 and none of them work for me,  any ideas guys?

I've tried **tovidgui**, **bombono dvd**,and **mestelix**, they are all so very confusing is there any program like **dvdflick** that is just straight to the point?

Comment: Have you tried the default burner installed with 12.04 Brasero? It simple to use and "straight to the point"

Answer (score 23):

### Brasero Disc Burner

Comes as a default application in Ubuntu. Supports features like on-the-fly burning, multi-session, on-the-fly conversion of music playlists in all formats supported by GStreamer and so on.

Click on your Dash and type **Brasero** to access it and give it a try

OR

If its not installed (for whatever reason) you can install it from the **Ubuntu Software Centre**

[image: brasero screenshot]

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Which category should i choose to make a `photo cd/dvd` ?

Answer (score 12):

### K3b

is a CD and DVD writing ('burning') application and is available from the **Ubuntu Software Centre.**

**Key Features include**

> Write data disks
>
> Write audio disks
>
> Write 'images' to disk (e.g. Linux distributions)
>
> Copy disks Rip and encode audio CDs

[image: k3b screenshot]

[image: Install via the software center]

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/K3b)

Comment: KDE default burner with KDE dependencies

Answer (score 11):

### [DeVeDe](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/devede) [image: Install devede]

This is quite a simple DVD authoring tool that claims to create simple DVDs that can be played on a home DVD player.

[image]

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 4):

Nero
or try imgburn
Both of them should work for ubuntu 12.04.3
At least they workd for me.

Comment: This is Windows software

Comment: @Joren Both Nero & Imgburn are available for Ubuntu as well. If you downvoted the answer, please undo it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Another lightweight option is [Xfburn](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/xfburn). It comes with Xubuntu and Lubuntu, too.