# How to use CD in way similar to a usb like you can Windows

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, cd

I'm currently using Lubuntu but this seems to happen in other Distros as well. I can't copy files onto a CD without burning it, however in Windows you can use a CD in a similar way to USB where you can put files on and off as you please. So for example, I can't drag a PDF from my documents folders onto my CD folder, as it say it's a read-only. I 've tried changing it's permissions to read and write but it won't let me, saying it's a read only file system. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when we copy file to CD without burning process in Windows, we just copy the file to windows temporary folder. It will not be permanently written to the CD.
Please correct me if I am wrong, but when you move the CD to other computer, the file will not be able to be opened or will not be exist on the CD.
Therefore, it would be not absolutely true if in this case we compare the function of CD and USB as similar.

The easiest way to solve the problem is to use CD burning app or program in Ubuntu.

As examples, please check these pages:

[What cd/dvd burning software should I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162129/what-cd-dvd-burning-software-should-i-use)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning

Good Luck